# Inertia.reload() Laravel Inertia React Project

Tags: reactjs, laravel, inertiajs

Is it a good practice to use `Inertia.reload()` in your laravel project when you want to reload your component after a post request? If you think there is another way that would be better don't hesitate to suggest me.

**Front React**

```
    const addToFavorite = async (videogameId: number) => {
        await axios.post(route("favorites.store"), {
            videogame_id: videogameId,
            user_id: currentUserId,
        });
        Inertia.reload();
    };
```

---

```
     <button type="button" onClick={() => addToFavorite(videogame.id)}>
        <StarIcon />
      </button>
```

---

**Controller**

```
    public function store(FavoriteRequest $request)
    {
        $favorite = Favorites::create($request->all());
        $favorite->save();

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think it's better to use built-in [Inertia.js Manual visits](https://inertiajs.com/manual-visits) using the `router.post` method

So your code will look something like this:

```
import {router} from "@inertiajs/react";

router.post(route("favorites.store"), {
            videogame_id: videogameId,
            user_id: currentUserId,
        }, {
            preserveScroll: true,
            onSuccess: res => {
                console.log('do something on success')
            },
            onError: err => {
                console.log(err)
            }
        })
```

You can use [preserveScroll](https://inertiajs.com/manual-visits#scroll-preservation) so you can prevent resetting the scroll position of the document body. This creates a seamless transition on the page.

And since you're already using `return redirect()->back();` in your controller, you don't have to manually reload the page.